# How to specify the width of a frame when using grid in tkinker

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I want to fix the width of my frame in this program.It is changing when clicking button.How can i set it to a default value.I did this program using tkinker .

```
import tkinter as tk
import math


class pythagores:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.label = tk.Label(master, text="base")
        self.label.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.base = tk.Entry(master, text="base")
        self.base.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(master, text="altitude")
        self.label1.grid(column=1, row=2)
        self.altitude = tk.Entry(master, text="altitude")
        self.altitude.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.button=tk.Button(master, text="Hypotenues", command=self.hypotenues)
        self.button.grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(master, text="")
        self.label2.grid(row=4)

    def hypotenues(self):
        try:
            alt = float(self.altitude.get())
            bas = float(self.base.get())
            hyp = math.sqrt((bas * bas) + (alt *alt))
            self.label2['text'] = "Hypotenues is .."+str(hyp)
        except:
            self.label2['text'] = "Wrong Input"
            return


root = tk.Tk()
pythagores(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read about [Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) and [Tkinter.Wm.resizable-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.resizable-method)

Comment: Hi stovifi thanks for your reply.I am very much new tot gui program. I added this line but it is not getting changed .root.resizable(height = 300, width = 400)
Can  you please help me

Comment: Should read: `root.resizable(height=False, width=False)`

Comment: By changing the code like this
pythagores(root)
root.resizable(height = False, width = False)
root.geometry('500x500')
I got  the window resized.But my buttons and labels above the button are shifting towards right

Comment: Your `Label` needs more columns, change to `self.label2.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='nw')`. Or make both blocks independant by enclosing it in a own `Frame`. Read [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: thanks stovfi.For that valuable piece of information